# using Laravel Query builder to exclude certain string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Let us say I have a table named `table` and it has the column called `path`, the string format in the `path` is like following

```
row path
1   /path1/aa/bg/c/da
2   /path1/ab/v
3   /path1/a/ba/ca
```

As you can see, each segment is separated by the char `/`.
How to format the condition in the `where` using `like` so that the only row returned is `row 2` with `2 slashes`.

I tried
`DB::table('table')->where('path','LIKE','/path1/%/%')->get()`

But the query above will return all the rows due to the last `%`. How can I exclude `/` after the last `%` so that, the record which has the char `/` after the last `%` will not be included in the result ?

Comment: You can use the regex method form mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html and the ```whereRaw()``` method instead of ```where```

Answer (score 1):

if you ar looking for match one character:

```
DB::table('table')->where('path','LIKE','/path1/_/_')->get()
```

"test%" matches all characters after

"%test" matches all characters before

"_" matches one character

ELSE if the string lenght you are matching is variable, you can only use regular expressions,

```
select * from table where path REGEXP '\/path1\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+'
```

more generic match matching special characters:

```
select * from table where path REGEXP '\/path1\/.+\/.+'
```

Comment: the length can not be determined since its dynamic. The pattern is for matching the segments against the segments stored in the `path` by comparing the number of `back slash`

Comment: the character after `back slash` can be a special character like `@`. Could you please help me to elaborate more on the pattern `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Does it try to match any alphanumeric character ?

Comment: here http://regexr.com/ you can test your regexp, for match @ you can use this \/path1\/[a-zA-Z0-9_@]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9_@]+

Comment: this cuold be the perfect regexp for you, please try it "\/path1\/.+\/.+"

Comment: Thank you very much. How to make the `@` to be optional ?. I guess `.+` matches any character right ?
The last one works well both in `Laravel` and also `phpmyadmin` but the first one works only in `phpmyadmin` but the last one will still return all the records